# Custom Keyboard Shortcuts to Programs not working after upgrade to 11.10 from 11.04

Tags: 11.10, shortcuts

I have an IBM Thinkpad x41 Tablet, and using this blog: http://wordsarelies.blogspot.com/2009/05/ubuntu-904-jaunty-on-thinkpad-x41.html

I was able to remap the tablet keys (the buttons right below the screen) to the unused keycodes 130, 131, and 132.

Then I was able to assign these keys to xournal, a script that rotates the screen, and cellwriter.

After upgrading from 11.04 to 11.10, pressing these keys no longer started the applications/ rotated the screen.

I looked at my keyboard shortcut settings, and it still registered that I was pressing the keys, but would not run the applications.

When I switched the shortcut to Alt+r (or anything else on the keyboard) It activated the programs with no problem.

I am at a loss at what to do to make these buttons work again and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 11.10 there seems to be a bug that prevents the "custom shortcuts" keys from working for favourite keys 3, 4 and 5 on the Microsoft 4000 keyboard. Maybe the x41's non-standard keys have a similar problem? Here's what worked for me:

- In a terminal, run: `gconf-editor`
- Navigate to apps/metacity/global_keybindings
- Change "run_command_3" to be 0xc2, "run_command_4" to be 0xc3, and "run_command_5" to be 0xc4 - these corresponds to the 3 / 4 / 5 favourite keys for the MS 4000 keyboard. Note: the x41s keycodes are likely to different, so sorry but I don't know what the corresponding keycodes are.
- Navigate to apps/metacity/keybinding_commands, and bind these run_command keys.
- For example, change "command_3" to be the take-screenshot command: `gnome-screenshot --window --interactive`
- Customize "command_4" and "command_5" as desired.